# ArcGIS Pro Symbology: Polygon boundary is displayed at the wrong size

Tags: polygon, symbology, arcgis-pro

This feels like a silly question, but ArcGIS Pro is displaying the boundaries of my polygons as very wide. Any suggestions on what settings to change to put it back to normal?

Image 1 below is the current display, with a 0.7 outline boundary. Image 2 is no boundary.

[image: How the polygons are currently displayed with a 0.7pt outline width]

[image: What I would like to have them displayed as (this has no outline, but it would be nice if there could be some!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference Scale can do this. Although it would have to be a very different scale to your current map scale to have that kind of effect. See: [Units and Symbol Size](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/units-and-symbol-size.htm) (Scroll down to the 'Reference Scale' section).